# Google sheet + App Script + Dialog + Triggers: Get dialog to keep showing from a triggered script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Hi here's my situation I run a script to generate a bunch of PDF and email them to a group of people but the script times out at about 30 person so I limited the script to generate the first 25 person from the list then the script create a minute trigger to start another script that will generate the next 25 person the issue I'm having is in my first script I use a dialog box that shows the reports being process and the total amount of report like this

[image]

On the first script started by a button the dialog box run with no problem but I can't seem to get it to keep working from the minute triggered script how do I get a dialog to work from a triggered script.

Thanks

Comment: You probably can't.  If a script is running off of a trigger then there is no user involved and no need to user interface.   Try just posting the information to a spreadsheet or some log file.

Comment: Can you share your code?